# PHP Form URL vars

Tags: php, html, sql

I was wondering if it would be possible to have a variable in the URL created when submitting a form?

form:

```
    <form class="register_form" action="action.php" method="get">
        Team Name*: <input type="text" name="teamname" required />
        Team Region*: <input type="text" name="teamregion" maxlength="4" required />
        Team Leader*: <input type="text" name="teamleader" maxlength="16" required />
        Team Members: <input type="text" name="teammembers"  />
        <input name="register_submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
```

I'd like the link to end up as: `http://.../action.php?do=register`

My reasoning for this is so that I can use action.php for more than one thing using if statements. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append the variable you want to the action link.

```
    <form class="register_form" action="action.php?do=register" method="get">
    Team Name*: <input type="text" name="teamname" required />
    Team Region*: <input type="text" name="teamregion" maxlength="4" required />
    Team Leader*: <input type="text" name="teamleader" maxlength="16" required />
    Team Members: <input type="text" name="teammembers"  />
    <input name="register_submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Or you can add a hidden field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="register" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the form action URL can have a query string:

```
<form class="register_form" action="action.php?do=register" method="POST">
```

The form data will be sent via `POST` but `do` will still be available via `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="register">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use any one of following methods

1) You can set the name of your `submit` button "do"; As the value of your submit button is "Register"

```
<input type="submit" name="do" value="Register" />
```

**OR**

2) You can add a hidden field to your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="register" />
```